# Recommended Way to Bulk Convert Typora Markdown to PDF using Pandoc

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc, github-flavored-markdown

The team I am on has dozens of markdown documents created using a Markdown editor called Typora (they won't want to switch to another editor). We would like to use pandoc to bulk convert the Typora markdown files to PDFs.  This would be included as part of a Jenkins build job, so exporting from Typora's GUI to PDF does not work.

Unfortunately, the PDF output has issues. Namely:

- Typora uses github flavored markdown which uses pipe tables. Pandoc does not autowrap the table entries causing the text to overflow off the right side of the PDF document.
- Code blocks fail to wrap. Though, I think I can solved this [using the listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121601/automatically-wrap-the-text-in-verbatim).

Here is the pandoc command I am trying to use:
`pandoc --standalone --from=gfm+pipe_tables --to=pdf -V geometry:margin=1in --shift-heading-level-by=-1 --resource-path=.:images:jenkins --table-of-contents intputfile.md --output=outputfile.pdf`

Based on my research, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to correctly convert Typora's markdown to PDF unless I use a pandoc filter or change pandoc's default latex template. Does that sound right?

Disclaimer: I am new to latex and pandoc, so I hope my question makes sense. I appreciate any help.

Comment: if you're new to LaTeX, maybe you want to use a different [pdf engine like `wkhtmltopdf`?](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf)